# creating page navigation unable to hide and show containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

i am trying to do a single page navigation, but unable to show and hide other containers.

basicall, it is 3 links . i capture the click event and set the appropriate container hide or show with sliding effect.

code is shown below. Thanks for help.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
    .current
    {
        display: block;
    }

    #about_container, #principles_container, #programs_container
    {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id^=btn_]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            //here you can also do all sort of things
            var elementToShowId = this.id;
            elementToShowId = elementToShowId.replace("btn_", "") + "_container";

            alert(elementToShowId);

            if ($('.current').exists()) {

                $(".current").hide('slide', { direction: 'right',
                    complete: function () {
                        show(elementToShowId);
                        $(this).removeClass('current');
                    }
                }, 500, null);
            }
            else {
                show(elementToShowId);
            }

            if ($('.active').exists()) {
                $(".active").removeClass('active');
            }
            $(this).addClass('active');

          });
      });


      function show(elementId) {
        $("#" + elementId).show('slide', { direction: 'left', complete: function () {

            $(this).addClass('current');
            if (elementId == "contact") {
                initializeMap();
            }

        }
        }, 500, null);
    }

   </script>
  </head>
<body>
 <ul>
    <li><a id="btn_about" href="#about"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
    <li><a id="btn_principles" href="#principles"><strong>Principles</strong></a></li>
    <li><a id="btn_programs" href="#programs"><strong>Programs</strong></a></li>
 </ul>
  <div id="home_container" class="current">
    Home</div>
  <div id="about_container">
    about</div>
 <div id="principles_container">
    principles</div>
 <div id="programs_container">
    programs</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle demo!

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3432c/ . by default the home container should be visible. when somebody clicks about the about container should be visible and other containers should be hidden

Answer (score 0):

U can try this:

```
#about_container, #principles_container, #programs_container
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
```